# Table reordering for responsive

Tags: html, css

Having a HTML table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>O</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>P</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Q</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>R</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>T</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>U</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>V</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>Z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

looking like so:

[image]

which is all good, now on small screens I would like to have only one `<td>` per `row` but keeping the right "Alphabetical" order. So it should be looking like so:

[image]

Is there a way to change this by CSS only to get the desired result? I've created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5eweva69/

Comment: Hide the original table and have another table displayed. (Using CSS `@media` queries)

Comment: @SimplyCraig two reasons why I wouldn't like that. 1. the table gets generated in a website CMS editor like (ckeditor or tinyMCE) so it's hard to generate a seccond table.. 2. it's bad habit to have double "code" to show the same and show/hide for responsivness

Comment: Use alternative tags (divs or lis, etc.) instead of tables.  It is inherently inflexible to what you want to do.

Comment: @Morfie thanks for your comment, probably that's the only solution. I wanted to ask here on stackoverflow to check if I misst some special crazy css hack and some people here just know crazy lots a stuff..

Comment: Any comments from the downvoters!? if you don't know the answer is no reason to downvote :)

Comment: I agree - not worth a downvote.  It's because of this table structure that there's simply no way to make it happen.  DIVS or other elements are a better option.  I have an answer below that with a jsfiddle, that mixes table and divs... but probably best to avoid tables with responsive design

Comment: Yeah, the poster has a lot of SO points, he isn't a noob.  The question is an honest one, so don't downvote. caramba, I like @deebs answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree about using DIVS or some other option, but if you're stuck on tables - What about divs within a table?  fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nvnghLn7/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="leftSide">
         <div>A</div>
         <div>B</div>
         <div>C</div>
         <div>D</div>
         <div>E</div>
         <div>F</div>
         <div>G</div>
         <div>H</div>
     </td>
     <td id="rightSide">
         <div>N</div>
         <div>O</div>
         <div>P</div>
         <div>Q</div>
         <div>R</div>
         <div>S</div>
         <div>T</div>
         <div>U</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then set #leftSide and #rightSide to display: block on smaller screens. (Setting TD to block won't work with dome doctype declarations, so using DIVS altogether is really the best option.)

Comment: Thanks @Morfie and deebs for your comments above and your answer. I fixed it with `<ul><li></li></ul>` as it really seems to be the best untill W3C sees my post and make the tables go responsive :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can do it using the `< table >` element, `< td >` tag signifies a column  and `< tr >` signifies a row, no CSS can change this structure, unless you request the `W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) Community` who makes the HTML Standards.

Well you can achieve similar results using bootstrap or `< div >` or `< ul >` list

Good Luck though.. :)